# How to get the last 5 value of each column

Tags: excel, vba

Is there another way to get the last 5 of a the column concatenated?

like image:
[image: like image]

```
   Sub lastn()
     
    lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(3).Row
    lRow1 = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(3).Row - 1
    lRow2 = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(3).Row - 2
    lRow3 = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(3).Row - 3
    lRow4 = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(3).Row - 4
    
    a = Range("A" & lRow).Value
    a1 = Range("A" & lRow1).Value
    a2 = Range("A" & lRow2).Value
    a3 = Range("A" & lRow3).Value
    a4 = Range("A" & lRow4).Value
    
    Cells(1, 1) = a & a1 & a2 & a3 & a4
        
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your image, you can use something like the following:

```
Public Sub LastFiveRows()
    Dim lRow_last As Long
    Dim oRng As Range
    lRow_last = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set oRng = Range("A" & lRow_last - 4 & ":A" & lRow_last)
    Cells(1, 1) = Join(Application.Transpose(oRng.Value2), "")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a Loop:

```
Option Explicit

Sub lastn()
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Cells(1, 1) = ""
        Dim lrow As Long
        lrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        
        Dim i As Long
        For i = lrow To lrow - 4 Step -1
            .Cells(1, 1) = .Cells(1, 1) & .Cells(i, 1)
        Next i
    End With
            
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Concat()` function with `Offset()` and `Resize()`

```vb
Cells(1, 1) = WorksheetFunction.Concat(Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(-4).Resize(5))
```

The same with the check for missing five cells:

```vb
Public Sub LastN_ErrHandle()
    Dim lc As Range
    Set lc = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
    If lc.Row < 5 Then
        Cells(1, 1) = "Five cells are not available"
    Else
        Cells(1, 1) = WorksheetFunction.Concat(lc.Offset(-4).Resize(5))
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I dont know why your code give me error 438  in worksheetFuntion.Concat( ------I'm using excel 2016  by thank you

Comment: Concat() is available in Excel 2019+